# Putting automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have lesson schedule table :

```
ID      Lesson    date        time1   time2    Teacher
-------------------------------------------------------
M001    Math     01-08-2017   17:00   19:00
M002    English  01-08-2017   13:00   15:00
M003    Design   01-08-2017   17:00   19:00
M001    Math     02-08-2017   13:00   15:00
M002    English  02-08-2017   17:00   19:00
M003    Design   02-08-2017   17:00   19:00
```

I also have teacher table with priority

```
ID      Name     Lesson    Priority
-----------------------------------
001     John     Math         1
002     Mike     Math         2
003     Clara    Math         3
004     Noah     Design       1
005     Jack     Design       2
006     Kath     English      1
007     Steve    English      2
```

Priority is determined who will be teaching at the schedule, but if the schedule already put the teacher the second teacher will be put on the schedule and so on.
I still confused how to make it work..please help..

Thanks...

Comment: And what is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

you wanna try inserting with a stored procedure

could look like this

```
CREATE STORED_PROCEDURE SP_INSERT_TEACHER

@TeachID int = 0,
@TeachName nvarchar(max), 
@TeachLesson nvarchar(max), 
@TeachPriority int

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF dbo.Teacher.Lesson = @TeachLesson AND dbo.Teacher.Priority = @TeachPriority
@TeachPriority + 1



INSERT INTO dbo.Teacher(ID, Name, Lesson, Priority) 
values(@TeachID, @TeachName, @TeachLesson, @TeachPriority)

END
```

This basically checks for existing records and pushes your inserted teacher back for 1 in terms of priority if a record already matches the lesson

just make sure to then always insert via the SP

Comment: There're 7 records of the teacher's with the different priority, so could it run until the end of the teachers record end? like putting do while or something..thx